# Area chosen for magnetic flux

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Let us say we have a square frame of side $a$. We project a magnetic field $B$ perpendicular to the plane of the frame to only one half of the frame.

So in this case to find the induced emf what should be the flux associated with the frame, $B*a^2$ or $B*a^2/2$, i.e., should I consider half the area or the complete one?

Comment: Have you learned the definition of flux as a surface integral?

Comment: It has been introduced to us as the dot product of B and A

Comment: In that case, the A is only the area where there is a B.

Comment: Why is it so? To find the flux through the frame shouldn't we consider the area of the frame itself?

Comment: *Why is it so?* Because of the real definition of flux as a surface integral. If you enlarge the frame to infinite size, but only a fixed part of it has field passing through, you shouldn't expect the flux to be infinite. There is no field “fluxing” through most of the frame.

Comment: @G.Smith oh I get it.... My teacher just told me that flux is just number of field lines passing through a surface. It's making sense now. Thanks!